# How to efficiently get an image patch with arbitrary orientation?

Tags: image-processing

For example, to get a long thin patch along a straight edge.

I have two possible ways of doing this:
1. rotate the input image, and doing in the normal way
2. calculate line equations and get the coordinates of pixels that lie in this patch

Does anyone have effcient ways of doing this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is using a ROI before rotating, you can look here for reference: http://answers.opencv.org/question/497/extract-a-rotatedrect-area/

Comment: @RosaGronchi thank you for the link. I found no easy way to do this. What I did is using a rotated patch as a mask to get the ROI.   I think the problem is that doing this operation frequently is not a good idea.